# Change the value by condition in another column (with if statement)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to select values greater than 50 in the column, and so where is it true to change the column value to Yes. Without if condition I understand how to do it:

`df3.loc[df3['Text_Count'] >= 50, 'big'] = "Yes"`

However, I need to do it with an if condition.

I tried this, but nothing changes after using the code:

`for index, row in df3.iterrows(): if [row['Text_Count'] >= 50] is True: row['big'] = 'Yes'`

My DataFrame:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De9t3.png)

Comment: Why do you need to use an `if` condition?

Answer (score 0):

Using indexing is clearly the best practice but if you need a loop, you can use:

```
for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    if row['Text_Count'] >= 50:
        df3.loc[index, 'big'] = 'Yes'
```

Try with `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np

df3['big'] = np.where(df3['Text_Count'] >= 50, 'Yes', 'No')
print(df3)

# Output
   Text_Count  big
0          52  Yes
1          12   No
```

Comment: Yes, that looks better for me, I'll try like this then! Thank you.